# Working with many to many association

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity

I'm trying to work out how to work with many to many relationship and have this selected using a checkboxes and have this recorded using EF4.1. And MVC3.

Say for example I have two entities :

Entity:Person
*-Id
-firstName
-secondName

Entity:Equipment
*-Id
-name
-height
-width
-weight

The association between the entity Person and the entity Equipment is many to many.

What I want to do in the create person page, I want to display the contents of the equipment entity/table as checkboxes. Upon the form submit I want to create the person entity and store the selected checkboxes.

If someone can show me how I can achieve this, I'd be greatful.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Hi, yes I have but I don't know how to read back dynamic set of checkboxes.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question: what have you tried? How does your current code look like? What specific difficulties did you encounter?

Comment: Well I don't have code to support this yet, I'm stuck and don't know how to do it. Hence my question here.

Comment: Probably a good place to start: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of steps.

1. Define your entityies
2. Configure a ManyToManyRelationship
3. Build the MVC contollers and views.

To define the Entity Objects

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    /// other fields

    public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipment { get; set; }
}

public class Equipment
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    /// other fields

    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

The DBContext Class

```
public MyContext :  DBContext
{
    DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    DbSet<Equipment> Equipment {get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()    // configure the many to many relationship.
            .HasMany(m=>m.Equipement)    // not required but I like to be explicit
            .WithMany(m=>m.People).
            .Map(m=>m.MapLeftKey("Person_Id")
                     .MapRightKey("Equipement_Id)
                     .ToTable("PersonEquipment");
    }
}
```

I like to use one view model per view
    public class CreatePersonViewModel
    {
        public Person person {get;set;}
        public IEnumerable equipment {get;set;}
        public int [] selectedEQuipment  {get;set;}  // this will come back in the post
    }

The Controller

```
public class PersonController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult CreatePerson()
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            var newPerson = new CreatePersonViewModel
                   {
                       person = new Person(),
                       equipment = db.Equipement.ToList()
                   }

             return View(newPerson)
         }
    }
}
```

The View

I wont do the entire view but this is pretty self explanitory.  There ary many examples of this on this site.  The Key is to set up the equipment array so you get the equipment ids back when you need them.  I will use ASPX for the view but you can use Razor

```
<%
    foreach (var e in Model.Equipement)
    {%>
        <input name="selectedEQuipment" type="checkbox" value=<%: e.Id %> />
        //// display the label for the checkbox anyway you want with whatever markup you need.
    <%}
%>

...

<input type="submit" />
```

The key piece is that you name all of the inputs the same and the name match what is in the ViewModel and that all of this is inside of an Html.BeginForm(), including the submit button.

The Http Post Metnod in the Controller

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult CreatePerson( CreatePersonViewModel viewModel)
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            // either use client side validation or server side validation

            db.People.Add(viewModel.person);
            // make sure the Equipment array in the viewModel is not null
            var equipment = from o in db.Equipment where viewModel.selectedEquipment.Contains(o.Id);
            foreach (var e in equipment)
            {
                viewModel.Equipment.Add(e);
            }

            db.SaveSchanges();
             // go somewhere using Redirect of some sort
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a stab in the DARK.  You are asking for a solution without providing details so here goes..

There are many ways to approach the " I want to display the contents of the equipment entity/table as checkboxes"

Some of the options are use a grid component and add a checkboxes to the grid as selections.
then loop thru the grid for each selection.

Simple way is query the person, I would say just use txtboxes and bind to fields then
binding the equipment grid (this will get the related equipment items.)
you can do a query method like this.
Passing in id

```
dim q = from Equip in context.equipment
        from Peeps in context.Person
        where peeps.id = id
        select Equip
```

you will then need to loop thru the results and check each box in the component you use using the query above

(This is one technique I use, there are others)
When you want to save changes.

Save persons first.
then
  I would check if something changed on the grid, if it did, query all existing records in equipment related to person and delete (use EF Clear method) all related, then loop thru equip grid for all checked and save back to equimpment.  This will add all changes.
Rebind grid.